# Polls application -- django tutorial not working

Tags: python, django

I followed the instructions in [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/)

I made one change for debugging, here are the files:

mysite1\urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^abc/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^polls/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

File: mysite1\polls\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^&', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Now if I go to the site `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/` then it shows the login page same as going to the site `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`.

However, if I go to the site `http://127.0.0.1:8000/abc/` it gives me the following:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/abc
Using the URLconf defined in mysite1.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^abc/
^polls/
^admin/
The current URL, abc, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Can someone guide me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "url(r'^&', views.index, name='index')," should be "url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),"  (note the dollar sign, signifying the end of the url :) )

Answer (score 5):

In `mysite1\polls\urls.py` It should be

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

Notice that your code had an `&` instead of `$`. `$` indicates a end-of-string match character.

Answer (score 0):

I had a few issues with this, maybe it'll help someone. My VS code was running python 2.7 so the first line on page urls.py in the web project folder (not the polls folder) I had to change to "django.conf.urls import include, url" from "from "django.urls import include, path". I had to include .conf. and urls, path was not working and it was not working without "conf".

Another issue I had on this same page is I had to correct it to "urlpatterns = [url('', include('hello.urls'))..." from "urlpatterns = [path('', include("hello.urls"))". Path was not working so I got this to work.

The third thing is, Notice that there is a '' in the code. It should be blank otherwise when you go to url http://127.0.0.1:8000/ it doesn't redirect to views.py in the polls folder.

I hope this helps someone. Thanks